# PHP Regular Expression pick up matches only after certain word in text

Tags: php, regex, pcre, preg-match-all

that's my first question here. :)
Was searching around with my problem for a few days, but it is not yet fully solved. 
What I have is a bunch of text. There is some price data divided by exact phrase "**promoted-after**" . So here is my RegEx:

```
'/price-([\d $гр€\.]*)/i'
```

It awesomely works for ALL the prices it founds including prices before divider. But when I modify it to:

```
'/promoted-after.*price-([\d $гр€\.]*)/is'
```

It correctly bypasses the top part, but then saves only one last price of all the data. How can it be modified to correctly save only all the prices AFTER "promoted-after" tag? 
Here is the example of input:

```
price- 2680 $
a lot of some random html code here
price- 3250 $
a lot of some good html code here
price- 3450 $
promoted-after
price- 400 $
a lot of some strange html code here
price- 401 $
a lot of some awesome html code here
price- 402 $
a lot of some ugly html code here
price- 403 $
a lot of some nice html code here
price- 404 $
a lot of some best html code here
```

P.S. I use preg_match_all

EDIT: Ok, let's just ignore that it's HTML. Let it be plain text. What is the overall logical construction behind such a task should be?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454

Comment: Do it in two steps: get the text after your "marker", then scan that text for your targets.

Comment: Your html is broken. Where are closing `</p>` tags?

Comment: @revo it's not valid HTML of course. I scraped pieces just for a quick example. Ok, I'll edit it so that it will be just a plain text.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you might use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) and use an xpath expression to find the div with the id `promoted-after` and then find all the siblings `p/strong`.

You could get their value using [nodeValue](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue).

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$items = $xpath->query('//div[@id="promoted-after"]/following-sibling::p/strong');
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo $item->nodeValue . "<br>";
}
```

**Result**

```
400 $
401 $
402 $
403 $
404 $
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/FZtT3)